# strongswan: received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have two private network.
**network A**

- router: TL-WVR3200L
- public IP: 223.71.239.218
- subnet: 192.168.1.0/24

IPSec config:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**network B**

- router: TL-WDR5620
- public IP: 119.90.63.105
- subnet: 192.168.100.0/24

I setup strongswan on 192.168.100.102 with following config:

```
config setup
        charondebug="all"
        uniqueids=yes
        strictcrlpolicy=no

conn bgp-to-corp
        authby=secret
        leftid=119.90.63.105
        leftsubnet=192.168.100.0/24
        right=223.71.239.218
        rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
        ike=3des-md5-modp1024!
        esp=3des-md5!
        keyingtries=0
        ikelifetime=1h
        lifetime=8h
        dpddelay=30
        dpdtimeout=120
        dpdaction=restart
        auto=start
```

When I run `ipsec start`, I found the following error in /var/log/syslog:
[image]

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: Does the responder actually support IKEv2? If not, try configuring `keyexchange=ikev1`, otherwise, check the log there to see why it send the notify back.

Comment: @ecdsa Thank you very much! TL-WVR3200L doesn't support IKEv2, when I configuring `keyexchange=ikev1`, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL-WVR3200L doesn't support IKEv2. As suggested by [ecdsa](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/64300/ecdsa),  when I configuring `keyexchange=ikev1`, the problem was gone.